# Break a loop when pressing a key

Tags: python, keyboard

I would like to stop a loop when I press the space key.

This is what I have tried:

```
def simulate(self):
    for x in range(self.repeat):
        if (keyboard.is_pressed('space')):
            break
        time.sleep(self.timer)
        keyboard.write(self.key)
```

Why is that not working?

Comment: What's `keyboard`?

Comment: @Rawing https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/

Comment: Works as expected for me (on linux). Are you perhaps tapping the space key for a short time? Try holding it down until the loop stops.

Comment: @Rawing I am holding it down. Still doesn't work. I am on Windows.